# Why don't more vampires in the Buffyverse use guns?

Tags: weapon, vampire, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

What's the in-universe explanation for why more vampires in the Buffyverse don't use guns?

Darla does in the first season and here and there, we see vampires use guns. But most seem to eschew them.  Why?

Comment: Guns suck on anything that that is not mortal? And if its mortal, why bother with guns? Check the part to [Live action tv](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GunsAreWorthless)

Comment: It’s called a Uzi, chump! Would’ve saved your ass right about now!

Comment: because its no fun and you waste some good blood ^^

Comment: http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer

Comment: *"Guns would make the show a whole lot shorter if they were widely used. They tend to be viewed as a bad thing, because Whedon hates them. Buffy fights with olde worlde weapons - crossbows, swords, er- hungamungas. In the Buffyverse there's something dishonorable about using a gun - only morally unpleasant characters use them (Darla, Cain, The Gruenstahlers, Lilah, Faith, Warren, Wesley) ... Wesley's continued reliance on guns reflects his increasingly unforgiving outlook."* - http://buffy-boards.com/threads/guns-in-the-buffyverse.18660/

Answer (score 2):

There's no real in-universe reason and, as you mention, Vampires do seem to occasionally use them.

That said, guns require background checks. If you are dead that's probably going to be a pretty big flag to stop a gun sale.

Also, Vampires can pretty much rip humans in half - strength wise - they really don't need them.

Comment: I don't think the undead would consider background checks much of an obstacle. After all, they can send their human minions to buy firearms for them, *or* take them from the bodies of their (armed) victims :)